# He creado un login en laravel y cada vez que registro un usuario se queda en ese usuario como evitarlo?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, login

pues esa es la duda, tengo un proyecto terminado de no ser por el login, lo he creado y a parte de que he tenido que registrar el primer usuario desde otro proyecto (para crearlo en este tenia que estar logueado, pero no existían usuarios). Ahora lo que no tengo ni idea es de como hacer que cuando registro un nuevo usuario se quede el actual logueado y no pase al nuevo.

P.D.: no posteo código porque el código es el por defecto cuando creas un login en laravel

Comment: Me he perdido, ¿que estas haciendo?

Comment: He creado un login con la consola de laravel y por defecto cuando registras un usuario inicia sesion con el usuario que acabas de crear. pero yo lo que quiero es que si estoy logeado con admin cuando creo el usuario Manuel quedarme en admin. se que es comentar una linea en el vendor, pero no se ni de que archivo ni de que linea se trata.

Comment: Si estas usando la ruta de register, estando logeado no te debería ni dejar entrar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la ruta "proyecto"/vendor/laravel/framework/src/illuminate/foundation/auth, en el archivo RegisterUsers.php, hay una función llamada register. Pues comentando una línea se soluciona.

```php
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    //$this->guard()->login($user); /*comentado esta línea se deshabilita el auto login*/

    return $this->registered($request, $user)
                    ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

[Fuente original en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43226145/laravel-5-4-disable-auto-login-after-registration/43226585)

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor que puedes hacer para que no te pase ello es realizar el registro con un metodo personalizado, es decir creas un metodo y haces el registro sin usar las funciones predeterminadas de laravel porque si las usas siempre va a pasar lo mismo, o modificar el vendor y eso no es muy etico editarlo

Answer (score 0):

Solo debes copiar y pegar el siguiente metodo que se encuentra en la ruta "proyecto"/vendor/laravel/framework/src/illuminate/foundation/auth, en el archivo RegisterUsers.php

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    // $this->guard()->login($user);

    return $this->registered($request, $user)
                    ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

lo pegas en tu controlador "`registerController`" en la carpeta auth y esto reescribira ese metodo del vendor.